# Deploy ARM template first and then deploy application secondly

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, github-actions

I am using Git as my repository and I am use Git actions to execute my flow.

[image]

According to the image I have four files.

InfrastructureMain.yml => execute the ARM template related stuff
ResourcesMain.yml => execute the application related stuff.

My Question is When I make PR to different environment the both InfrastructureMain.yml and ResourcesMain.yml starts to execute, but I want to firstly execute the InfrastructureMain.yml and then when it gets success, then execute ResourcesMain.yml.

to fulfil my requirment. Is there have any configurations to do?

Comment: Could you put them in the same yaml file so that you make them dependent on each other?

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you. but due to company policy has to separate it.

Comment: What about it if you'd make a third one to include the two others? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) on trigger a pipeline after another by the way.